# Blazor WebAssembly site gives 404 after updating to 3.2.0 Preview 2

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I've been working on a Blazor WebAssembly site built from the 3.2.0-preview1 template.  I want to update versions, so I am first going to update it to **preview2** [per these instructions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/).  I do so and all seems well: my site compiles, and I can run it and hit all server-side breakpoints without errors. Thus, my ASP.NET host is spun up and listening on https://localhost:5001.  But when I try to view the site locally, I get an immediate 404, as if routing never kicked in or as if it cannot find my component with `@page "/"` on it.

**Any idea how I can troubleshoot this?**  I am at a loss because I get no error message anywhere.  I have nothing I can tweak on the server side, as it all seems to be working, and I have nothing I can tweak on the client side, because it isn't loading a client at all.

I have also tried updating all the way to **preview3**, but unsurprisingly, the very same symptom results.

I am using dotnet.exe version 3.1.300-preview-015048.

Here's my `dotnet run` output and the browser with network tab: [image]

Comment: Can you post the network log ?

Comment: What network log?  From the browser?

Comment: I've posted the browser network tab as well as `dotnet run` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you aren't depending on .NET 5 prerelease packages when you meant to depend on v. 3.2 prerelease packages.  This will be better after Blazor WebAssembly is in full release.